# 413 Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, iis-6

Let me start this off by saying I've searched this error far and wide and tried a few presented solutions (see below) but nothing seems to work and I continuously get the dreaded 413 error.

**Basics:**
Everything is written in C# using .Net 3.5, and we are using IIS 6

I have a WPF client application that talks to a 'middleman' WCF web service (basically just a forwarding service that will be exposed to the internet), which talks to the workhorse WCF web service (this is where all the code is defined and it sits nicely behind our proxy, accessible only on the internal network)

Currently, the 'middleman' service is running locally on my machine, but will be deployed to an internet-exposed IIS box in time.

**The Situation:**
When I attempt to send data to the server from the client, it kicks back the 413 error.  The data I'm sending is only about 41kb (according to Visual Studio).  I tried sending back a minimal file size (15bytes) which did work.  It should also be noted that this error did not happen while I was testing the server on my localhost.

**What I've done:**
We have used the console command on the IIS box to increase the UploadReadAheadSize to 130670.  In addition, I've modified all the App.config and Web.config files for the client and two services to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize & masStringContentLength to 2147483647

**The plea for help:**
So I ask, what I have I missed?  What else is there to do?

Comment: In my web.config system.web/httpruntime element, I have an attribute maxRequestLength="10000" which specifies in kilobytes the size of incoming requests. Does it apply to your problem ? You should also test with lower values than 2147483647 (that might overflow to unwanted values)

Comment: BTW : 130670 is size in bytes. Seems far from 41,5 kbytes but you might want to give a try to an higher value...

Comment: I have tried what you suggested (dropping the maxRequestLength down, and also have increased uploadReadAheadSize to 1310670) but I still get the same error.